Will it be beneficial to my application if I include in a research proposal the fact that all my papers improve papers published at top conferences?
During my undergraduate studies, I was actively engaged in reading research papers and even discovered a significant result. However, after spending about 10 months trying to write a paper on it, a team of five researchers from a prestigious US university published the same result before I could. This experience led me to avoid tackling problems that seemed to require lengthy solutions, and as a consequence, my subsequent work has been less theory-dense.
Most of my papers now improve upon results that were presented at top conferences, yet none of my papers have been accepted at these top venues. I suspect that one other reason for the rejections might be the lack of recent activity in the areas I'm exploring.
Will it be beneficial to my research proposal if I include in a research proposal the fact that all my papers improve papers published at top conferences?

Application for what, exactly?

@Buffy Research proposal.

More precise please. For doctoral admissions? Masters admissions? Grant application? Faculty application? Something else?

Are you in academia or trying to enter it in some way?

By "improve" are you in a field like ML where "improvement" means some marginally better performance by some measure (computational speed, "accuracy", etc)? The sorts of "improvement" papers you describe in that field are mainly junk, even if they are popular to publish in certain venues. The improvements rarely generalize, the specialization is rarely justified.

Are these improvements that are obvious and not done previously because other people just thought it was too easy to bother with, or improvements that required genuine insight?

If it looks like an excuse and quacks like an excuse - it is an excuse. You keep looking to make excuses. Start looking for positive reasons some committee should support your proposed work.

@Buffy It's a grant application. The papers that I have were presented or published at A-rated conferences.

@AlexanderWoo The improvements were to problems that may have been avoided by more serious researchers as they likely have known that the benefits of solving them didn't outweigh the effort/time cost of solving them. But I don't think they are trivial in any way.

@Kupp - In my field, funding is so scarce that a researcher at your level (or mine) would not even bother applying for grants.  Only people with successful approaches to the most interesting problems get them.

@AlexanderWoo, my word, you are pessimistic about funding acquisition... it is not always/everywhere as bad as you suggest.

I would try not to emphasize the fact that your work is unoriginal and simply piggybacks off existing works, regardless of how good those original works are, and the fact that you may have "improved" them.
I would think really hard about what you brought that is unique and try to shift the focus on what your unique contributions are, rather than on the perceived prestige of the original works you have decided to "improve".
Your rejections from top conferences are because you are likely presenting marginal "improvements" or peripheral studies to original works.

Yes it's true my improvements are considered marginal but they are far from being trivial. These problems may be avoided by more serious researchers as they likely know that the benefits of solving them probably don't outweigh the effort/time cost of solving them. I was thinking of just putting a single line in my application about the fact that most of my papers improve papers that were published at top conferences. What do you think?

Was your work published at top conferences? If no, then the community has decided that it is not of that level, so it does not matter where the work you are following up was published. I think it is best to avoid all focus on the derivative factor of your work, and rather focus on what you bring to the table, especially if you say the work is non trivial. If you cite your statements in your proposal accurately, then readers can look it up and come up with their own opinion as to the impact of the area you are working in.

Triviality is not binary but a continuum.  If, on a scale of 1 to 10, what you're calling trivial is everything that is a 1, and your work is a 3, it's still not good enough to get funded.

@AlexanderWoo I would say the average result is about 7 on your scale of difficulty. They are elementary results that are probably difficult to discover.

Yes, including that all your papers improve upon work published at top conferences can significantly strengthen your research proposal. It highlights your ability to push the boundaries of current knowledge and positions you as a competitive and impactful researcher. Just ensure to support this claim with specific examples or metrics if possible.

Actually the correct claim here is that the OP thinks they have improved on other people’s work, and this is highly subjective unless the OP is very clear on what has been improved and how.  So it’s a gamble to push this kind of storyline as the other side of the bet is that someone will read the relevant literature and might disagree or just find the claim exaggerated, neither of which are good outcomes.

@ZeroTheHero doubt the author of the answer can answer your comment, as it's likely a GenAI answer, not their own.

@ShadowWizard interesting observation re: possible AI-generate contents.

@ZeroTheHero well, this user posted more obvious GenAI answers on different sites, so it's just a pattern. On some sites it's allowed (sadly), but I hope here it's not.

@ShadowWizard amen to that!
